# WordPress plugin that has sliders with title

Tags: wordpress

I would like a wordpress plugin that can have titles on the image slides. The same as this drupal site.

[Image Slides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10mX0.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many plugins for that. But which I used is Slider Revolution and LayerSlider Plugin.